# Playing "Executive Orders" on self

Tags: battlestar-galactica

I just played my first game of BSG (solo using the official fully cooperative rules). I've got the german edition so my card names might be a bit off...

The green skill cards 1 and 2 say something like:

**Action:** Choose 1 player. This player may move his character and do 1 action OR may keep his character where it is and do 2 actions

Now if it is my turn. Can I move to a location in my move phase, play that card in my action phase, choose myself and do the location's action 2 times? It seems a bit overpowered but I've not seen anything in the rules that forbid this use...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The English version of this card specifies OTHER players:
[image: Executive Orders card]

So, no, you cannot play this card on yourself.

Comment: Also remember to check the Errata and FAQ.  Only one executive orders per turn, so no chaining them.

Comment: Arghh, translations... Thanks for clearing that up.