# Use of Executive Order in Battlestar Galatica

Tags: battlestar-galactica

As seen in this question ...[Playing "Executive Orders" on self](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/2733/playing-executive-orders-on-self)

Executive Order lets another player take 2 Actions if they don't move.  From my understanding of the rules this means the other player could:

1. Play another Executive Order on me, allow 2 players to take many actions in a row.
2. Allow Cylons to do as listed above, which can be devastating.
3. Allow a player to move out of Sickbay without penalty.
4. Allow a player to move out of jail (does Executive Order 'allowing moving' trump jail 'not allowing moving'?)

This seems too powerful.  We play with the following modified rules.

1. No chaining, 1 Executive Order allows the receiving player to play any action other than an Executive Order.
2. A player may use the Move to exit jail, however this forfeits the 'action'.

Does anyone have an official rule source on this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Much of this is covered in the **FAQ and Errata**, which you can find a link to [here](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/edge_minisite_sec.asp?eidm=18&esem=4).

1. You can't play 2 Executive Orders on the same turn.  Under **Errata**:

   > The “Executive Order” Skill Card should include the following
   >   text: Limit of 1 “Executive Order” card may be used per turn.
2. Revealed Cylons can't play Executive Orders on each other (though *un*-revealed Cylons, sure!). Under **Cylon Players**:

   > Q: Can a revealed Cylon player be targeted by the “Executive
   >   Order” Skill Card or Quorum Cards?
   > A: No.
3. Yes. Under **The Brig and Sickbay**:

   > Q: Can a player in “Sickbay” move out of that location if
   >   targeted by an “Executive Order” Skill Card?
   > A: Yes. If the player moves out of “Sickbay” before the start of
   >   his turn, then he will not be restricted to drawing a single card.
4. I read it that a player may not move out of the Brig voluntarily, not even due to an Executive Orders free move. I don't think anything explicitly states this rule, but I generally feel that "You may not move" from the Brig trumps the "You may move" from Executive Orders.

As for your house rules, the first rule is good (and in the Errata).  The second rule *seems* to be not strictly in the rules, and I personally don't think it's a good idea - it would make Executive Orders more powerful than it already is (which is already quite powerful!) and the Brig less bad.  The Brig is supposed a scary place to be and hard to get out of; being able to Executive Order someone out of it seems like it diminishes that too much for my tastes.

Comment: I believe the Brig says "you may not move" and Executive Order says "you may move", so I can see where someone could be confused as to which one trumps the other. We have always played that EO cannot get you out of the Brig. My interpretation is that the Brig prevents you from moving. EO simply grants the option to move, just as your normal turn does. The Brig prevents the movement in both cases. A more technical ruling might be that the Brig's restriction is mandatory, while EO's ability is optional. In general, mandatory trumps optional.

Comment: @Todd Hm, perhaps you could read it that way. For some reason I assume that "You may not" always trumps "You may" (not just in this game but others I am used to).

Comment: I agree. I thought that's what I said. Was I not clear?

Comment: In most games I've played that have similar level of game text effects that deny something usually beat effects that allow the same thing. Also like others said. XO'ing someone out of the brig feels unrealistic and cheap.

Comment: @Todd that is what you said. You were quite clear. The brig's movement restriction trumps Executive Orders.

Comment: As an extra note from the FFG FAQ, you can't be forced out of the brig (e.g. into sickbay), and you can't be the one chosen to be brigged/sickbayed when a choice is forced if you're already there (though you could brig someone in sickbay).